# Library for creating PowerPoint-Presentations

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint, openxml

is there a (.net-)library for creating PowerPoint-Presentations (PPTX => OpenXML).
For creating Excel-sheets I like [ClosedXML-Library](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/73027) and would love something similar for PowerPoint.
I can't and don't want to use Microsoft Interop because it is an ASP.NET Web-App.

Does someone has any experiences creating PowerPoint-Slides in ASP.NET?

P.S.: I had a look at [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx) but found it little to expensive.

Comment: Were you able to do what you needed? I'm surprised nobody else commented on this question. I'm also working on a website that needs to create/manipulate PowerPoint presentations so if you come across anything other than OpenXML SDK let me know.

Comment: as I wrote it seems like I have to use Open XML. I still struggle with it but the SDK Tool is great help.

Comment: There are some simple situations where the SQL Server Reporting Services SSRS report render libs can produce a very simplistic PPTX from rdl .  Dubious real world usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned OpenXML but have you tried the OpenXML SDK?

Download from: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: To me it seemed a little complicated. I will have another look at it.

Comment: Yes I also think it's complicated but, MS has provided a tool "OpenXMLSDKTool.msi" which is available on that page that you can use to decompile powerpoint pptx files and it will give you a code listing to see how it can be created from code.

Comment: Although I found it really "ugly" it seems like I have to use Open XML. I will mark this as answered although I am not confident at all.

Comment: The OpenXML SDK is complex. The OOXML tool is nice and the decompiled code listings are great but it doesn't make up for the complexity in using the SDK at all. I'm going to continue to keep looking for something a bit easier to use. If I find something I'll let you know.